# I though I knew everything about Enum but how does this work

Tags: java, enums

I though I knew everything about Enum but how does this work

(thanks to [Fumihiko Shiroyama](https://github.com/srym/FirebaseRealTimeChat) for the code

```
/**
 * Message Type
 *
 * @author Fumihiko Shiroyama (fu.shiroyama@gmail.com)
 */
public enum MessageType {
    NORMAL(1 << 7), IMAGE(1 << 8);

    private int flag;

    MessageType(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Especially how does the >> work here?

Comment: It's a bitwise left shift (`<<`, in the code). `>>` is a bitwise right shift (and not in the posted code).

Comment: I know how the bitwise shift work but not like this what´s the purpose

Comment: It sets one bit on in the `int` (a different one for each `MessageType`). Presumably to create a bitmask.

Comment: Can the `flag` for the `NORMAL(1 << 7)` be anything else then 128? or how do you mean?

Comment: `1 << 7` and `1 << 8` are just expressions which produce an `int` value. And you said, you understand them. So what you see here, is an `enum` having an `int` field that can be queried via `getFlags()`. Enum types are classes which can have fields, methods and even implement interfaces. So what obstacle does the combination of these two features create?

Comment: thanks it was just confusing why not write `(128)` instead of `(1 << 7) `

Comment: To emphasize that this number has the 7th bit set to one, likewise that the other constant has the 8th bit set to one. Code is not only saying what should happen, it’s also documentation. That’s why we also use, e.g. named constants instead of their actual constant value or why we give classes meaningful names instead of calling them, e.g. `Class1`, `Class2`, and `Class3`, etc., despite they still would work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because **MessageType** needs in every Field (NORMAL and IMAGE) a constant integer at the time the code is compiled...

as soon as you compile, this **NORMAL(1 << 7)** will be calculated as **NORMAL(128)** and the rule is not broken

which rule:

those values in the constructor must be Constants at compiling time

Answer (score 0):

The enum type called MessageType defines a constructor

```
MessageType(int flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}
```

for every enum constant (NORMAL, IMAGE) with passed value flag, which is passes when the constants are created:

> NORMAL(1 << 7)
>   and 
>   IMAGE(1 << 8)

Later the value flag can be retrieved:

```
NORMAL.getFlag()
```

take a look at this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), it also has more examples